# Work with ZIP archive at Bash

Tags: linux, bash, zip, unzip

I need to write a simple Bash script. How to unzip archive (in the same directory) with several files and get a path to these unpacked files? Path to archive is in $1 attribute. And how to pack these files back in new archive with $2 path? Thanks

UPD:
I try this:

`filenames=(zipinfo -1 $1\)
extension=".csv"
unzip $1
for i in "${filenames[@]}"
do
   :
   newfilename=${i:0:${#i}-4}$extension #change extension to .csv
   #...do smth...
   zip -r $2 $newfilename
done`

But in the archive there's empty file ".csv" (without name, olny extension).ъ

UPD2: solved, it was because of test directory named "abc", I did a comparsion on the last character "$last" = "/" and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the zipfile is foo.zip, to unzip the archive, you can do

```
unzip foo.zip
```

and to list the files in the archive you can do

```
zipinfo -1 foo.zip
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I write files in the archive to variables in the script?

Comment: You can capture the output of the list of files in the archive with `var=(\`zipinfo -1 foo.zip\`)` This will store the files into the `$var` array. `${#var[@]}` will give you the number of elements in the array, and `${var[n]}` will let you access the `nth` element of the array.

Comment: One more moment, what if there're files in directories in archive? How to correctly do with this?